# Shading the surface of the 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, parametric-functions

I have the 3D plot here. Is there any way to color or to shade the curve's surface?

```
b = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{i, y, -y^2 + 2}, {y, -4, 4}], {i, 1, 8}];
Show[b, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-4, 4}, {0, 3}}]
```

I have try to use `FaceForm` but it didn't work.

Comment: The code produces eight 2D curves.  Is that what you had in mind?  If so, do you want each curve to have a separate color, or to shade each of the eight curves with varying color?

Comment: Yes, it creates 8 curves and I want to shade the "space" between the curves so that it looks like a surface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps, this is what you had in mind.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{i, y, -y^2 + 2}, {y, -4, 4}, {i, 1, 8}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x]], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-4, 4}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

The code in the question instead produces eight 2D curves.  With similar coloring, they look like

```
b = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{i, y, -y^2 + 2}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    PlotStyle -> Hue[(i - 1)/7]], {i, 1, 8}]; 
Show[b, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-4, 4}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

If uniform colors are desired between each curve, then use

```
a = ParametricPlot3D[{i, y, -y^2 + 2}, {y, -4, 4}, {i, 1, 8}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[Round[x - 1 - 1/14, 1/7]]], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-4, 4}, {0, 3}}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50];
b = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{i, y, -y^2 + 2}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Black], {i, 1, 8}];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Just to illustrate use of [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html). Using Bob Hanlon's function:

```
f = Hue[Round[(# - 1)/7, 1/7]] &;
ParametricPlot3D[{i, y, -y^2 + 2}, {y, -4, 4}, {i, 1, 8}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-4, 4}, {0, 3}}, MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), 
 Mesh -> {Range[2, 7]}, MeshShading -> (f /@ Range[7]), 
 MeshStyle -> Thickness[0.005], BoundaryStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image]