# Shading a surface bound by a curve in 3D

Tags: plotting, mesh, parametric-functions

## Foundation

### Input: unit circle

The exercise deals with transformations of the unit circle, $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. We start with the unit circle with Hue coloring over the angular range of $(-\pi, \pi)$ as seen below. The green shading denotes a region of right-handed chirality. (As you travel from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, the interior is on the left.)

[image: unit circle]

### Transform in 2D

The transformation in two dimensions is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\sin \theta\\
\cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
\Longrightarrow
\frac{\sin \theta} {1 + \cos^2 \theta}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
\cos \theta \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The transformation twists the circle into this racetrack figure:

[image: 2d]

The two lobes separate regions of right-handed chirality (green, left) and left-handed chirality (red, right). The point of the exercise is to show how the unit circle was twisted and mark the chirality of the connected domains.

### Transform in 3D

The transformation in three dimensions is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\sin \theta\\
\cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
\Longrightarrow
\frac{\sin \theta} {1 + \cos^2 \theta + \cos^4 \theta}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
\cos \theta \\
\cos ^2 \theta
\end{array}
\right)$$

In Mathematica the transformation is cast as:

```
fields = Sin[\[Theta]]/(1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^4) {1, Cos[\[Theta]],Cos[\[Theta]]^2};
```

This code snippet produces the plot, a gently rolling racetrack:

```
ParametricPlot3D[fields, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4 0.8] &),
  PlotRange -> {1.05 {-1, 1}, 1.05 {-1, 1}},
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image: 3d]

## Question

How do I shade the two interior zones (left in red, right in green) bound by the curve?

##### Reference

This post looked promising, but ultimately, I could not use this to solve the problem.

[Shading the surface of the 3D plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131843/shading-the-surface-of-the-3d-plot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f[θ_] := 
  Sin[θ]/(1 + Cos[θ]^2 + Cos[θ]^4) {1, 
    Cos[θ], Cos[θ]^2};
ParametricPlot3D[
 f[θ]*(1 - s) + 
  f[-θ + π] s, {s, θ} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[{0 <= s <= 1, 
    0 <= θ <= π/2 || 
     3 π/2 <=  θ <= 2 π}, {s, θ}], 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4 0.8] &), SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

The method can be illustrate by the follow figure,

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[
  f[θ]*(1 - s) + f[-θ + π] s, {s, 0, 1}, {θ, 
   0, π/2}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, PlotStyle -> None, 
  MeshStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[θ], {θ, 0, π/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green], 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[-θ + π], {θ, 0, π/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Cyan]]
```

[image]

we draw the `f[θ], {θ, 0, π/2}`(green),and reverse part of `f[θ]` by `f[-θ + π], {θ, 0, π/2}`( cyan),and then draw the red segment from green to cyan by  `f[θ]*(1 - s) + f[-θ + π]`